# JPA - Primary key prefix

Tags: java, jpa

We have a table where the ID is generated by a trigger -

> ID = year+month+sequence

I mapped the table via JPA and I would like to use the same PK generation in my code as well. I tried the following options:

```
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "assetSeq", sequenceName = "ASSET_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "assetSeq")
    @Transient
    private long id;
```

and also tried to change the setter

```
   public void setId(long id) {

        String finalId=getIdPrefix()+id;
        this.id = Long.parseLong(finalId);

    }

    private String getIdPrefix() {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMM");
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        return df.format(today);
    }
```

but non of them worked. I just want to insert new record in the database and do not want to use the id later. I use Hibernate for JPA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you implement custom Hibernate generator. [This blog](http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2009/01/custom-hibernate-sequence-generator-for-id-field/) has almost identical example to what you need. I'll post here the code from the blog adjusted to your needs (might not work if you copy-paste it, but it will be close)

```
public class CustomIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
            throws HibernateException {

        String prefix = getIdPrefix();
        Connection connection = session.connection();
        try {

            PreparedStatement ps = connection
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT nextval ('ASSET_SEQ') as nextval"); // could be different, depending on database vendor

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("nextval");
                String code = prefix + id;
                return code;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException(
                    "Unable to generate ID");
        } finally {
            if (ps != null) {
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // log error, or rethrow exception
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String getIdPrefix() {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMM");
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        return df.format(today);
    }

}

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name="seq_id", strategy="my.package.CustomIdGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator="seq_id")
// don't put that @Transient here
private long id;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you're using a sequence, why not generate the value with a trigger? That way, you can ensure that all clients will always use the generated IDs from the sequence...

Comment: Good idea, that would be a better approach.

Comment: It would be good, but if I set the Id to transient, it still uses and Id in the insert statement - this was my first approach

Comment: Any way of doing this in JPA?